# Display chart in the template

Tags: python, django, templates

I have this code: http://pastebin.com/BVZ73NBk

I'm trying to send the graphic to the template, but this error is occurring:

TypeError at /grafico/

draw_graph() takes no arguments (1 given)

Request Method:     GET
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:

draw_graph() takes no arguments (1 given)

OBS: I use Python and Django

Can you help me? Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling `draw_graph` as a view, it needs to accept the `request` as an argument.